# Different results in JDBC and MySQL for SQL select where datetime > date

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to select a subset of entries from a table based on the DATETIME. In the command line, I enter

```
SELECT * FROM routes_table WHERE time > '2012-05-28 11:01:01' ORDER BY time
```

I get

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM routes_table WHERE time > '2012-05-28 11:01:01' ORDER BY time;
+-----------+--------------+------+---------------------+--------------+
| driver    | type         | num  | time                | destination  |
+-----------+--------------+------+---------------------+--------------+
| Ma Lvjing | Bus          | B127 | 2012-06-22 15:00:00 | Colina Hotel |
+-----------+--------------+------+---------------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, when exactly the same query is executed through JDBC, I get all the results of the table, including the entries whose time is earlier than '2012-05-28 11:01:01'. Any idea why is this happening?

This is part of the JDBC code, in a JSP

```
String database = "routes";
String routes_table = "routes_table";
String column_time = "time";
<%
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //Load the MySQL driver
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"
                + database, "root", "admin");
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        String currentDATETIME = new TimeToolbox().getCurrentDATETIME();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + routes_table + " WHERE "
                + column_time + " > '" + currentDATETIME + "'"
                + " ORDER BY " + column_time);
%>
```

Comment: Okay now that we have that, what's `TimeToolbox`? Are you sure that `getCurrentDATETIME()` is returning correctly? I strongly recommend you use prepared statements btw.

Comment: can you also show the SQL generated from your code

Comment: If I add to the code a System.out.println
System.out.println("SELECT * FROM " + routes_table + " WHERE "
     + column_time + " > '" + currentDATETIME + "'"
     + " ORDER BY " + column_time);
The SQL query generated is:
SELECT * FROM routes_table WHERE time > '2012-05-28 11:01:01' ORDER BY time
Then I just copy-paste it into the command line, and get the different output.

Comment: @Paul Bellora TimeToolbox is the class where I generate the DATETIME, I'm positive it's done correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) with parameters and a [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) variable to pass the value of the date, in this way you most likely resolve the problem and prevent SQL Injection ...

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + routes_table + " WHERE "
                + column_time + " > ?"
                + " ORDER BY " + column_time;
PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(query);
prest.setDate(1,new Date());
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems that it doesn't work either.
`code`String selectString = "SELECT * FROM " + routes_table + " WHERE " + column_time + " > " + "?" + "" + " ORDER BY " + column_time; System.out.println(selectString); PreparedStatement selectEntries = con.prepareStatement(selectString); selectEntries.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis())); System.out.println(selectEntries.toString()); selectEntries.execute();
`code`
And it generates SELECT * FROM routes_table WHERE time > '2012-05-28' ORDER BY time But same outcome